# Native App Auth Flow in Azure Active Directory

Tags: azure, authentication, react-native, azure-active-directory, azure-web-app-service

I have a React Native app, calling an Azure Api App authenticated with Azure Active Directory, where the associated app in *App Registrations* is of type *Native*.
I have tried using a *Web app / API* application type (multi tenant). I switched away from that though, because I thought I wouldn't have to provide a `client_secret`. That didn't work, but I prefer that way, since I can control which tenants have access to my api.

I currently get a `code` by displaying *https://login.microsoftonline.com/common/oauth2/authorize...* in a webview where the user signs in and consents. I then try and get an `access_token` from aad - haven't successfully gotten an `access_token` without storing the `client_secret` in the app.

Every user of the app is registered in an Azure Active Directory tenant on another account - the app is not public, so I manage users.
All the authentication flows I have looked at don't seem like they fit my criteria though. I'm obviously not the first with this problem in Azure so I need need someone to tell me where I'm going wrong. Thanks :)

Comment: Your React app should be registered in AAD as Native, and your API should be registered as Web app/API. Normally you would use implicit grant flow to get an access token for the API from the front-end. If you need to authenticate users from another tenant, either a) the app must be multi-tenant (you can setup a set of valid issuers in your API to check they came from one of the valid tenants) or b) you invite them as guests into the tenant where the apps are registered + change the authorization endpoint to include the tenant id instead of common.

Comment: And how should this be done? Should I auth against the native app, and through the native app provide permission to the web api? What application(client) id should be listed in the Api App Advanced Authentication?

Comment: Exactly, and you should use the APIs client id there :)

Comment: Hi. Follow up question if thats alright. I can successfully get an `access_token` from the _Native app_, but parsing it as `Authorization: Bearer <access_token>` to the api app returns: _IDX10501: Signature validation failed. Key tried: 'System.IdentityModel.Tokens.X509AsymmetricSecurityKey_. Under _required permissions_ I have have added the _Web app / API_ application type. The only scope I have in the constent/auth request is _openid_ though. Any ideas as to why its not letting me access the api?

Comment: That's odd.. Its basically saying that it has a signing key (which it should download from the authority) but it doesn't match the signature on the token.. Is your backend authority set to the common endpoint?

Comment: No... I was using the _orginizations_ endpoint, because when I use the _common_ endpoint I get the error: _(<appname>) is not supported over the common or consumers endpoints. Please use the organizations or tenant-specific endpoint_. Using _organizations_ I was actually able to get an `access_token`

Comment: Then it sounds like you are mixing v1 and v2 endpoints. The v1 endpoint (which you mention in the question) has no organizations endpoint. You should use the v1 endpoint in the backend too

Comment: It's actually working, I can't believe it. I have spent the last 3 weeks authing different apps in Azure, and I gotta say, it's been a pain in the *** BECAUSE I didn't ask people who actually knew what they were doing for help. Thank you so much, for the quick and informative replies :) !

Comment: No problem :) I'll try to compile the comments into an answer tomorrow.